# UIImage Not Transparent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to make a view that lets a user draw with their finger. I have a png made in Pixelmator of the brush. My drawRect: method looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    NSAssert(brush != nil, @"");

    for (UITouch *touch in touchesNeedingDrawing)
    {
        //Draw the touch
        [brush drawInRect:CGRectWithPoints([touch locationInView:self], [touch previousLocationInView:self]) blendMode:0 alpha:1];
    }

    [touchesNeedingDrawing removeAllObjects];
}
```

The brush image is a png with transparency, but when I run the app, there is no transparency. Does anyone know why, and how to fix it?

**Edit:**
I discovered that the image is transparent, but when I call `drawInRect`, the image draws the transparent pixels as the background color of the view. Is there a CGBlendMode I can use to fix this?

Comment: brush is a UIImage, just to clarify.

Comment: why can't you use an UIImageView?

Comment: Because I would need hundreds of UIImageView subviews, which would be impractical. I am trying to let a user paint with their finger with a brush image, and each time their finger moves, I would need a new UIImageView. I would also have problems deleting.

Comment: You don't need an UIImageView for every touch. Actually the usual way to do this task is to create an UIImageView and draw on it based on user input.

Comment: I'm doing almost what you're suggesting, only I'm just using a UIView. Every time someone drags their finger, I tell the UIImage to draw itself at that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it could be taking the current fill color of the context.

Try setting the fill color for the context with CGContextSetFillColorWithColor() to [UIColor clearColor].CGColor

If that doesn't work, the only other solution that is simple and shouldn't have a performance hit is to have 2 views:

- Background View - This will be view that has the proper background color or image
- Overlay View - This view will detect the touches etc and then draw all of the brush strokes on top.  The background color of this view can then be [UIColor clearColor] so when you draw the brush images, the alpha will be filled with [UIColor clearColor].  Basically the same view you have now, just with a clear background.

Note: You shouldn't need to mess with the blend mode to make this work. You should be able to use the default drawInRect: method

Answer (score 5):

Solution is very simple, testes on my own project. In class which you updated with custom `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` set in `-(id)init` background color for self

`[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

And thats all. Tested on my project.

Comment: +1. Great. Especially seeing the "I believe that...", "It seems like.." and "I should.." answers. Facts. Love it :-)

Comment: @moonlight — I think you meant "tested" on your own project, not "testes" on your own project.

Answer (score 0):

Is the brush png loaded to an imageView? That is, the variable *brush* is an object of UIImageView, isn't it?
If so, perhaps simple

```
brush.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

will help

Comment: i suggest making it a UIImageView. `UIImageView *brush = [UIImageView imageNamed:@"brush.png"];`

Comment: Btw perhaps it is the reason why I thought it's gonna be UIImageView. Seems I collided with the same problem, working with UIImage.

Comment: The only problem with that is that I'd end up with a huge number of views that I could never get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try destination out blend mode: `kCGBlendModeDestinationOut`.

You could also draw at point instead draw in rect:

```
[brush drawAtPoint:[touch locationInView:self] blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationOut alpha:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is that you are setting the blendMode to 0.  I suggest using the `-drawInRect:` method without a blend mode.  The issue may also be that your view has a black background, but that is doubtful. I would also suggest attempting to display the UIImage in a UIImageView as a test.  The issue may be related to the way that PixelMator exports images.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a fundamental misconception of how `drawRect:` actually works. Every time you draw something into the current graphics context, everything that was there previously will be cleared (so that only the `backgroundColor` remains).

Since you're only drawing the current touch(es) (`touchesNeedingDrawing` is emptied), there's nothing under the rectangle you're filling that could show the transparency of the image you're drawing, so the background color shows through.

You basically have two options to resolve this:

1) Keep all touches that contribute to the drawing around (don't empty the `touchesNeedingDrawing` array) and redraw all of them every time – this is going to be easy but quite slow.

2) Draw into a buffer of some kind (e.g. a `UIImage`, using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` etc.). Every time your drawing changes, create a new buffer. Draw the old buffer into the new buffer and the images for the new stroke on top of it.